# Using Image_data_generator preprocesing functions when predicting on one image only

Tags: keras

So I trained a CNN using Keras with a samplewise_std_normalization preprocessing function which is available when applying the Image_data_generator.

but when I try to predict only on one image the CNN does not work (obviously) because I did not perform this preprocessing when importing the one image.

does anybody have any idea how the code should look like to import only one image then apply this preprocessing function and feed it into a CNN?

Answer (score 0):

Those preprocessing are meant only for training. It is a technique called data augmentation. It is not meant to be used while testing.

Even then, in case you want to augment the images, you can use this library called [ImgAug](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in my experience the same kind of augmentation need to be performed when importing the test data also, otherwise the network is exposed to something entirely different and does not perform right... so I am still looking for a way to import one image by using cv2 or the keras library itself and perform this specific augmentation before feeding the image into the network.

Comment: I do not agree when you say the test data also needs to be augmented. I think you are confusing preprocessing with augmentation here. If you are to augment every test image before prediction, why augment the train set in the first place during training? The reason augmentation is done is so that we have a more varied datasets which would account for different variations that could come in testing time.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying but the terms withing the keras framework can be rather loosely used as the preprocessing and data augmentation can be done withing the same Image_data_generator function... what I meant to say is that if you normalize the training data you also have to normalize the test data because that is what the network is used to working with.